# condition in a nested for loop in C won't work

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to C and I'm practicing for-loops and pointers.
In this exercise I try to write a function that sorts array elements. the first part of the code (where I input the elements) is working, but everything below gives me a hard time. I don't understand if the problem is in the if/else statements or anywhere else in the loop structure. also the last loop doesn't work (I just want it to iterate over the sorted array and print the elements, like I did before with it unsorted.

Hope I can get some help, and  also if you see anything more that I should pay attention to...

Thanks a bunch.

I tried checking if the way I defined the loop was accurate, that I put all the right values and that the basic "idea" that I had for sorthing the array was ok.

```
void sort_array_elements()
{
int x, i, j, k, temp;
printf("\n input the number of elements to store in the array: ");
scanf_s("%d", &x);

int arrnum[30];
ptr_int = &x;
printf("input %d elements in the array: \n", x);
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    scanf_s("%d\n", &arrnum[i]);
}

printf("the elements in the array before sorting: \n");
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    printf("element %d: %d\n", i, arrnum[i]);
}


for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j < x; j++)
    {
        if (arrnum[i] > arrnum[j])
        {
            temp = arrnum[i];
            arrnum[i] = arrnum[j];
            arrnum[j] = temp;


        }
        else if (arrnum[i] == arrnum[j])
        {
            for (k = arrnum[i + 1]; k < x; k++)
            {
                if (arrnum[k] != arrnum[j])
                {
                    temp = arrnum[k];
                    arrnum[k] = arrnum[j];
                    arrnum[j] = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


    }

}

printf("the elements in the array after sorting: \n");

for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    printf("element %d: %d\n", i, arrnum[i]);
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest you remove all that `else` code block in its entirety. Anyway, you are indexing by `k` whose value depends on the input data. Suppose one array element value is 10000000? What will `arrnum[k]` access then?

Comment: You should say `if(x > 30) x = 30;`

Comment: What's the \n doing there in scanf? It makes you input n+1 numbers but you did not notice?

Comment: @iooshine Where is the variable  ptr_int declared and what is its meaning?

Comment: @iooshine And you should split the function in several other functions. For example one function enters an array. Other function sorts an array. And another function outputs an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain about your elseif statement in your sorting algorithm. The code can also potentially reduce runtime by not reiterating through sorted elements and only swapping the smallest element into the location of i. Also consider the use of the qsort built-in function for sorting arrays! I have a suspicion that your sorting algorithm is doing something weird to the array, which is why the loop to print the sorted array is not working. Also you are never using ptr_int, or pointers (well arrays are kind of pointers I suppose).

`

```
for(int i = 0; i<x; i++)
{
    for(int j = i; j<x; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] < arr[i])
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
 }
```

`

Comment: thank you!
I understand what you all said about the else-if not being necessary.
Also I saw the mistake I did in the "if" statement in the most inner for-loop and the problem I had with scanf_s inside the loop, doing one extra iteration because of the "\n".. it really helpd!

I know there is a built in function for sorting, but I wanted to try it "the hard way" myself for practice :)

Comment: @liooshine No problem! Do you understand why you can start j from the point of i in my example? If not I can try to explain it.  Also kudos to you for doing it the hard way, best way to learn!

Comment: Yes I understood! it's working now! :D 
Thank you very much for your help!!